# Hibernate id with GenerationType.AUTO constantly increasing

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm developing a web app using Jsf 2.2, PrimeFaces 5.1 and Hibernate 4.3.8 . In model class for a table, I have a auto increment primary key and It is working well with adding operation. This id definition like below.

```
@Id
@Column(name="id",nullable=false,unique=true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

In my xhtml page I have two h:form component with different ids. First form contains inputTexts to be saved and submit button and It is working well. The other form constains a dataTable that shows added records into database.

When I update  to added record in dataTable, I can update but auto increment value  constantly increasing. What was the reason for it?

Comment: public void updateUniversty(Universty universty){
  
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  session.update(universty);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();
  
 }

Comment: Assuming the RDBMS you are using is MySQL in which you are using an auto-generated primary key in which case, `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` should be `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and those JSF/PrimeFaces tags collectively generate merely a noise according to the question's nature. `GenerationType.AUTO` is used to automatically detect a strategy depending upon the database system in question which is basically not recommended.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL and my id field is serial primary key(auto increment value like mysql). Should I change the @GeneratedValue defination like you said ?